# Computing heightmap colour from input value with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a heightmap with `plot 'mydata' using 1:2:3 with image`.  The values in the third column range from -0.05 to 0.25.  I want to define a palette where negative values become more red and positive values become more green, with zero being white.  -0.05 and 0.25 should be fully saturated.  I have just realised that I can do this with

```
set palette defined (-0.05 '#ff0000', 0 '#ffffff', 0.25 '#00ff00')
```

but can this be done without knowing the upper and lower bounds in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to use the `stats` command to get the min/max when the script is run.

```
stats 'data.dat' u 3 nooutput
set palette defined (STATS_min '#ff0000', 0 '#ffffff', STATS_max '#00ff00')
```

This assumes that the min is below zero and max is above zero.  Otherwise you have to put some logic in to define palettes based on different situations.